# How to clone my website (cakephp) to localhost?

Tags: php, cakephp, localhost, wampserver

I have installed Wampserwer on my computer, and I have access to files on hosting via WinSCP.
Website is running on CakePHP

Can anyone, please, explain what steps do I need to do, to make a copy of my website on localhost. I cant find any usefull instructions
Thanks!
[localhost is working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PZWaU.png)
[access via winscp to files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y7bxv.png)

Comment: whats the issue you are facing, please share that or pay me I will configure site on your local :)

Answer (score 0):

- Copy the files to your computer
- If your site uses a database, you have import that one, too + create a user/password
- You have to configure your webserver for Cake. Find instructions here: http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/installation.html#installing-cakephp (in your case, search for Apache)